# The tour link has disappeared from the help menu in the top bar

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, tour

The Tour item disappeared from top bar on all sites:

> [image: The help menu in the top bar only showing three options but the Tour link is missing]

What's the background for this?

The Tour page itself still [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour).

Based on the question from RuSO.meta: [Куда делась ссылка на Тур в знаке вопроса (правый верхний угол сайта)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/13066/176217)

Comment: i wonder what affect this change has had on people earning badges for reading the tour, people do appear to still be earning it

Comment: @KevinB The actual tour page is still accessible, despite the link to it being gone, so I'd guess somehow the menu broke, but the rest of it probably would work fine. Of course, I could be incorrect, but maybe a staff member will chime in with what broke

Comment: @cocomac Right, it's more a curiosity of if losing that link had any impact at all on people reaching it. I'm sure it was a mistake, but even mistakes can be opportunities to gather data

Comment: Can't speak for anyone else, but I always got the tour link from the footer (or direct URL entry).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Update:** the fix is live across all sites. Thanks for the report and for your patience.

---

This was an unintentional regression.  We're working on getting a fix pushed out right now.  Will update when completed.